# How to insert/update a single record using a MERGE statement with Spring JDBC

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc

I have an update/insert SQL query that I created using a MERGE statement.  Using either JdbcTemplate or NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, does Spring provide a method that I can use to update a *single record*, as opposed to a Batch Update?

Since this query will be used to persist data from a queue via a JMS listener, I'm only dequeuing one record at a time, and don't have need for the overhead of a batch update.

If a batch is the only way to do it through Spring JDBC, that's fine... I just want to make certain I'm not missing something simpler.

Comment: Just use `update` method, for example this one: [JdbcTemplate#update](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) instead of BatchUpdate. `Update` updates a single record, `batchUpdate` updates multiple records using JDBC batch.

Comment: @krokodiko : Thank you! That is exactly what I needed to know.  You were first in, so if you provide an official answer, I will vote for your answer.  Everyone has been helpful.
   I initially tried Spring's update methods, but due to a problem with my parameterized list, I misinterpreted the exception and determined that UPDATE was not the right method. I had not realized that with Spring JDBC, it is simply a single or batch update. I looked for a more specific method and could not find one, so your short answer gave me the insight I needed to solve my issue. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use one of `update` methods, for example this one: [JdbcTemplate#update](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) instead of BatchUpdate. 
`Update` updates a single record, `batchUpdate` updates multiple records using JDBC batch

Answer (score 3):

You can use a SQL [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statment using only a one row query containing your parameters.

For example if you have a table `COMPANY`containg `ID`as a key and `NAME`as an attribute, the `MERGE` statement would be:

```sql
merge into company c
using (select ? id, ? name from dual) d
on (c.id = d.id)
when matched then update 
   set c.name = d.name
when not matched then insert (c.id, c.name)
   values(d.id, d.name)
```

If your target table contains the parametrised key, the `name` will be updated, otherwise a new record will be inserted.

With JDBCTemplate you use the [`update`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method to call the `MERGE`statement, as illustrated below (using Groovy script)

```
def id = 1
def name = 'NewName'

String mergeStmt = """merge into company c
using (select ? id, ? name from dual) d
on (c.id = d.id)
when matched then update 
   set c.name = d.name
when not matched then insert (c.id, c.name)
   values(d.id, d.name)""";

def updCnt = jdbcTemplate.update(mergeStmt, id, name);

println "merging ${id}, name ${name}, merged rows ${updCnt}"
```

Comment: I used Java, but your answer is absolutely correct.  Thank you for sharing this example.  Although I have used the update methods in Spring JDBC for many years, I am new to MERGE statements, and did not realize the update method was generic enough to handle a SQL statement that both updated and inserted.   
 I had actually tried it briefly, but had an issue with my parameterized list.  After that, I was looking for a more specific method, perhaps built for executing a MERGE.  Thank you for the example!